# Data on Demand without Parameter

Tags: spotfire, tibco

[Data on Demand option along with the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4n7l.jpg)I am creating a button to generate a report in Spotfire and a reset button to get back to original form of report displaying no data, I am using Data on Demand but it requires parameters(Input) to do which I don't have in my report functional specification.
Can anyone help me out to do this way?

Comment: Please edit your question with some code that shows us what your problem is, or what you’ve tried so far. See [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: I have added the image link in the question.Please see it.It has button and data on demand option.